# WinEdt vs TeXStudio: file not found

Tags: graphics, texstudio, eps, winedt

The same tex file works with WinEdt while opened with TeXStudio reports the following error:

```
File `Fig1' not found. ...h]{Fig1}
```

The piece of code follows

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}

....

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea? I don't understand why the same code works with an editor and not with the second one.

Comment: unrelated to your question but why load `epsfig` ??? which is a small wrapper around graphicx to emulate the old (1980's) epsfig package.

Comment: The editor you use is unrelated to the error message but perhaps syou are using latex with one and pdflatex with the other. Impossible to tell given the incomplete fragment of error message that you posted.